# Console commands to build a project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, command-line

I am working on Visual Studio 2008 edition. I need to build "class library" dll through "Console" commands. A simple command to do so would be:

```
"csc /target:library /out:File.DLL File.cs"
```

which creates File.dll successfully.

But what should be done to include a dll file as input? Eg: `Final.dll` needs a C# file named `Final.cs` and `File.dll`? I tried out the below command but unsuccessful

```
"csc /target:library /out:Final.DLL File.dll File.cs"
```

What is the exact way to do so?

In the same manner i tried adding project references in the command:

```
csc /target:library /out:Final.DLL /r:First.dll /r:../Func\Func.csproj Final.cs
```

But it tells the Func.csproj could not be opened and is corrupt. What could be the reason?

Comment: Is File.dll a *reference*? an *embedded resource*? or ....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a reference (most probably), you can add assembly references by using this option:

```
/reference:File.dll   (or /r:File.dll)
```

You can use it like the other options:

`csc /target:library /r:File.dll /out:Final.dll File.cs`

Remember you'll also need to distribute that Dll with your library.

Note: type `csc /?` to get a full list of all flags and help about them. It's a common command for many console applications like csc on windows.

Comment: How is it handled in case of project references?

Comment: @inquisitive csc doesn't handle project references. That's what msbuild does.

Answer (score 2):

```
csc /target:library /out:Final.DLL /r:File.dll File.cs
```

You add references with **/r**